# how to check the check boxes with retrieved data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have written script that to pass `json` data to a variable and after passing data. In the inner html page I collect all the data like `chapterid`, `questionid` ...etc

### jQuery Code:

```
$('div[id^="questionsNo_"]').ready(function() {
  var assessmentDataObj = [{
    "id": "1",
    "user_id": "1",
    "book_id": "64",
    "chapter_id": "1",
    "question_type": "",
    "question_id": "1",
    "option_id": "1",
    "mark": "0",
    "notes": "",
    "matchOption": "",
    "dragValues": "",
    "added_time": "1469595022"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "user_id": "1",
    "book_id": "64",
    "chapter_id": "1",
    "question_type": "",
    "question_id": "2",
    "option_id": "2",
    "mark": "0",
    "notes": "",
    "matchOption": "",
    "dragValues": "",
    "added_time": "1469622667"
  }];
  $("div[id^='questionsNo_']").each(function() {
    var fndDetails = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
    var fndChapterId = fndDetails[1];
    var fndQuestionId = fndDetails[2];
    $.each(assessmentDataObj, function(key, value) {
      if (assessmentDataObj[key].chapter_id == fndChapterId & amp; &
        amp; assessmentDataObj[key].question_id == fndQuestionId) {
        $('div[id^="questionsNo_' + assessmentDataObj[key].chapter_id +
          "_" + assessmentDataObj[key].question_id + '"]' +
          'p input.option_' + assessmentDataObj[key].option_id).attr(
          'checked', 'checked');
        var a = assessmentDataObj[key].option_id;
        if (assessmentDataObj[key].question_id == 1) {
          $('.option_' + a).attr('checked', true);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

### HTML Code:

```
<div id="questionsNo_1_1">
  <p class="text"><input class="option_1" id="ques11" name="radiobutton"
  type="checkbox" value="Yes"></p>
  <p class="text"><input class="option_2" id="ques12" name="radiobutton"
  type="checkbox" value="No"></p>
</div>
<div id="questionsNo_1_2">
  <p class="text"><input class="option_1" id="ques13" name="radiobutton"
  type="checkbox" value="No"></p>
  <p class="text"><input class="option_2" id="ques14" name="radiobutton"
  type="checkbox" value="Yes"></p>
</div>
```

According to the script I am able to check the `ckeckboxes` which is having `option_1` only in two questions.

I want only the `check box` should select according to the `json` data.
For that I have tried in this way in if condition I have added one more condition.

```
if (
  assessmentDataObj[key].chapter_id == fndChapterId & amp; & amp;   assessmentDataObj[key].question_id == fndQuestionId & amp; $amp; assessmentDataObj[key].option_id == fndOptionId) {
```

For getting `fndOptionId` value I write statement like:

```
var fndOptionId = $(this).attr('class').split('_')[1];
```

This was getting `Option_1` in the two questions.

How do the `checkboxes` should select automatically according to the json data.

Comment: your js is beautiful :D

Comment: but it was checking all the two options in each question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your javascript function:

```
   $('div[id^="questionsNo_"]').ready(function () {
    var assessmentDataObj = [{"id":"1","user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"","question_id":"1","option_id":"1","mark":"0","notes":"","matchOption":"","dragValues":"","added_time":"1469595022"},{"id":"2","user_id":"1","book_id":"64","chapter_id":"1","question_type":"","question_id":"2","option_id":"2","mark":"0","notes":"","matchOption":"","dragValues":"","added_time":"1469622667"}]; 
 $.each(assessmentDataObj, function (key, value) 
    {
    $("#questionsNo_1_" + assessmentDataObj[key].question_id).find('p input.option_' + assessmentDataObj[key].option_id).attr('checked', 'checked');         
    });
    });
```